# storing data in a file and parsing the file as json

Tags: python, json

I want to store data in a .json file as using python language-

```
    {object:
            {
              name: "abcd",
              id: "fwfwfwf"
            }
            {
              name: "efgh",
              id: "wderds"
            }
            ..
            .. and so on
    }

    {container:
            {
              name: "pros",
              id: "zxcdsef"
            }
            {
              name: "mnop",
              id: "waqsred"
            }
            ..
            .. and so on
    }
```

Again now I want to read particular member of object/container in the file using f.read() or similar methods.\

How can I parse this file using python and JSON ??

#

Sir One more thing I want to ask. Suppose my data.json file is like -

```
    {
        "object": [
            {
                "name": "abcd",
                "id": "fwfwfwf"
            },
            {
                "name": "efgh",
                "id": "wderds"
            }
        ]
    }

    {
        "container": [
            {
                "name": "pqrs",
                "id": "fwfwfwf"
            },
            {
                "name": "mnop",
                "id": "wderds"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now I want to add one more container in this file which will go under Containers.
Can you please tell me how will I write new container in the file using f.write()

Comment: The identifiers are actually in quotes, aren't they? Did you read the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) docs? That module is quite easy to use...

Comment: I agree with @Tim ... That doesn't look like valid json to me.  And, as he pointed out, the builtin json module should help you out if the file is actually valid json.

Comment: I am not familiar with json. I just showed my understanding there in the text. please help if possible.

Answer (score 2):

first create valid json. You can validate your json using any link [like](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
    "object": [
        {
            "name": "abcd",
            "id": "fwfwfwf"
        },
        {
            "name": "efgh",
            "id": "wderds"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now python script

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

And you can access data like:

```
data["objects"][0]["id"]  # will return 'fwfwfwf'
data["objects"][1]["name"] #will return 'efgh'
```

Comment: Sir, I have modified ques a bit based on your suggestions. Please help me on this too.

Comment: Acc to my understanding you should first read load the JSON from file then append your new entry in data["container"] bcz data["container"] is a list of dictonary.

Answer (score 0):

use `http://jsonlint.com/` to validate your json. In json files identifiers have double quotes. numbers int/float need not have.
In general a json file is a python dictionary in text format. You can use the json module to parse json files.

```
import json
myfile = open('yourfilename', 'r')
myjsondata_as_dict = json.load(myfile)
```

after this myjsondata_as_dict will have your json data as a dictionary, provided there were no errors in json format.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for dumping data into JSON prettily.

```
with open('abc.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump(obj, outfile, indent = 4)
```

For loading from JSON file, use

```
with open('abc.json') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```

More info http://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/storing-and-loading-data-with-json/